# histogram equalization transformation function

Tags: image-processing

Suppose that a given 3-bit image(L=8) of size 64*64 pixels (M*N=4096) has the intensity distribution shown as below. How to obtain histogram equalization transformation function 
and then compute the equalized histogram of the image?

```
Rk     nk
0      800
1      520
2      970 
3      660
4      330
5      450
6      260
7      106
```

Answer (score 6):

*"Histogram Equalization is the process of obtaining transformation function automatically. So you need not have to worry about shape and nature of transformation function"*

So in Histogram equalization, transformation function is calculated using cumulative frequency approach and this process is automatic. From the histogram of the image, we determine the cumulative histogram, `c`, rescaling the values as we go so that they occupy an 8-bit range. In this way, `c` becomes a look-up table that can be subsequently applied to the image in order to carry out equalization.

```
rk      nk       c        sk = c/MN       (L-1)sk     rounded value
0       800      800      0.195            1.365      1
1       520      1320     0.322            2.254      2
2       970      2290     0.559            3.913      4
3       660      2950     0.720            5.04       5 
4       330      3280     0.801            5.601      6
5       450      3730     0.911            6.377      6
6       260      3990     0.974            6.818      7
7       106      4096     1.000            7.0        7
```

Now the equalized histogram is therefore

```
rk           nk
0            0
1            800
2            520     
3            0
4            970
5            660
6            330 + 450 = 780
7            260 + 106 = 366
```

The algorithm for equalization can be given as

```
Compute a scaling factor, α= 255 / number of pixels
Calculate histogram of the image
Create a look up table c with
    c[0] =  α * histogram[0]
for all remaining grey levels, i, do
    c[i] = c[i-1] + α * histogram[i]
end for
for all pixel coordinates, x and  y, do
    g(x, y) = c[f(x, y)]
end for
```

But there is a problem with histogram equalization and that is mainly because it is a completely automatic technique, with no parameters to set. At times, it can improve our ability to interpret an image dramatically. However, it is difficult to predict how beneficial equalization will be for any given image; in fact, it may not be of any use at all. This is because the improvement in contrast is optimal statistically, rather than perceptually.  In images with narrow histograms and relatively few grey levels, a massive increase in contrast due to histogram equalisation can have the adverse effect of reducing perceived image quality.  In particular, sampling or quantisation artefacts and image noise may become more prominent.

The alternative to obtaining the transformation (mapping) function automatically is **Histogram Specification**. In histogram specification instead of requiring a flat histogram, we specify a particular shape explicitly. We might wish to do this in cases where  it is desirable for a set of related images to have the same histogram- in order, perhaps,  that a particular operation produces the same results for all images. 
Histogram specification can be visualised as a two-stage process.  First, we transform the input image by equalisation into a temporary image with a flat histogram. Then we transform this equalised, temporary image into an output image possessing the desired histogram. The mapping function for the second stage is easily obtained. Since a rescaled version of the cumulative histogram can be used to transform a histogram with any shape into a flat histogram, it follows that the inverse of the cumulative histogram will perform the inverse transformation from a fiat histogram to one with a specified shape.

For more details about histogram equalization and mapping functions with C and C++ code 
https://programming-technique.blogspot.com/2013/01/histogram-equalization-using-c-image.html